# trouble on wamp server after fresh installation

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have a newly installed wamp server. Actually i reinstalled it because
i was having problem with it previously. It was not starting anymore (offline, icon stays yellow). I reinstalled it hoping it would go back to normal. i have two servers running
on the server pc (sql server and wamp server). 
sql server is listening in port 80 and wamp server is listening at port 8000. This was working fine before i tried to add a new extension to the php server (php_mssql.dll).

now, on my newly installed wamp, im still having the same problem, the icon on the system tray
remains yellow. It does not go online. what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have any other service running on Port 80? e.g. Skype?

Comment: none sir, and i change the port where wamp is listening. I change it to port 8000.

Comment: What is there in your error logs (all apache, php, etc logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that port 8080 is empty .if you have installed skype any other software ,antivirus then first uninstall them and restart wamp server the wamp server it will turn in green

cause to wamp server stays yellow: port 8080 is not empty